# Google Tag Manager Image Clicks

Tags: html, sharepoint, google-analytics, triggers, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Analytics on a Sharepoint site. On the main page, we have an image in an image carousel that once clicked will bring you to a different page on the site. I have tried everything to track clicks on this image in GTM - click url, click ID, css selector, etc. I can not figure out why my trigger never fires. I have attached the
[image, what pops up when I click inspect,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sREbj.png) and [variables that show up with the click in GTM preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imDgL.png)... [(This is the second half of the variables in preview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOqNn.png).Three images total.

Comment: Looks like GTM is detect the <a> element far outside the element you want to track.
Can you give more complete screenshot for the image carousel or do you have idea where the <a> is ?

Answer (score 0):

Good job on including all the relevant debugging info.

Judging from your inspect, you're looking at the image.

However, judging from your click event inspection, the click lands on an a.

I don't see the a in your DOM on the screenshot, but it may be either dynamically added, or just outside of the screenshot.

No matter. Let's start to carefully debug it. Make a trigger that would be triggered on anything that matches a. That's just a debugging trigger. Make sure it triggers on your image clicks.

Now, let's just make a simple CJS variable that would `console.log({{Click Element}})`. No need to use it anywhere, just make it. Go to the debug view again, try clicking the banner again and look in the console for something that would look like this: [image]

See that pretty element? Now the wonderful dev console allows you to copy JS path to this element and do whatever you want with it. Mainly, comfortably and quickly test CSS selectors against this element. I suggest changing the selector JS console generated. It should work (unless the page is too dynamic), but it would be fragile. Having the element, however, you'll be able to make your own selectors.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am able to follow you up until the CJS variable. Once I create it in GTM, I don't see anything different in the debugging console...

Comment: you're supposed to see it in JS console. In Chrome devtools.

Comment: This is what comes up in the console: Error: Error: Idle tracking cookie is missing.
    at IdleSessionActivityMonitor.GetIssoCookieValue (activitymonitor.js:379:23)
    at IdleSessionActivityMonitor.InitializeSettingsFromCookie (activitymonitor.js:363:57)
    at LogIssoActivity (activitymonitor.js:130:26)

Comment: you're looking at the console in the GTM preview mode, right? Try inspecting the value of your CJS variable in there.

Comment: it says undefined for that value

Comment: you should check the value on the click event.

Comment: Yes, undefined is the value of the click event

Comment: ok, try using this CJS variable in a any tag on your <a> click trigger. Just to make sure the CJS runs and console.logs something. Although in preview, it should evaluate on every event. The JS error you're seeing is unrelated to GTM. Maybe check the different logging level in the console, like on my screenshot in the top right corner.

Comment: I am now able to see the href path in the console, but it looks just like a path to the webpage the image links you to

Comment: no, that's an element.when you hover over it, it will be highlighted on the page, you also can right click it, copy JS path, paste it in the console and get the element as a variable in the console for further debugging, but even knowing the path, you can build the path-based selector as in `[href="https://..."]` and try using in your a trigger.